# org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Apache xmlsec IdResolver could not resolve the Element for id reference

Tags: opensaml, xmlsec

I am trying to validate a SAML Assertion signature but getting the following error:

```
org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Apache xmlsec IdResolver could not resolve the Element for id reference: P_ZoIp8bCaGCKuf8Tqy1EckkF4_
    at org.opensaml.security.SAMLSignatureProfileValidator.validateReferenceURI(SAMLSignatureProfileValidator.java:153)
    at org.opensaml.security.SAMLSignatureProfileValidator.validateSignatureImpl(SAMLSignatureProfileValidator.java:84)
    at org.opensaml.security.SAMLSignatureProfileValidator.validate(SAMLSignatureProfileValidator.java:56)
    at com.test.AssertionValidator(AssertionValidator.java:341)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:646)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:501)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1040)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:607)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:315)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)"
```

I am using OpenSAML 2.6.1, XMLSec 1.5.6 and JDK7u51. 
Any way to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 2):

Common problem when decrypting and verifying signatures using OpenSAML. To solve this you need to set the RootInNewDocument property to true in you decryptor before decrypting. Like this

```
decrypter.setRootInNewDocument(true);
```

Ref.
http://mylifewithjava.blogspot.no/2014/05/exception-apache-xmlsec-idresolver.html